# Available options in SharePoint 2016 on-premise to print list items and have a custom print page with header,footer, etc

Tags: development, splistitem, 2016, list-form, printing

I am working on a team site collection inside my sharepoint 2016 on-premise. and i have added a custom list. now our customer asked us if we can implement the following to be able to print the list items:-

1. To have a printable view for the list items.
2. when printing a list item to show the company logo as the header, and on the footer to show the date printed and the site name where the item's list is added (the current site name). the page body should show the item columns and data.

now sharepoint 2016 does not provide any printing capabilities for the list items. so can anyone adivce how i can implement such a functionality ?

Comment: One workaround I can suggest you to use Chrome browser, open the list view page in the tab and just hit `Ctrl + P` to print the page. It will give the print as you like at certain level. Its not exact solution but one can try this.

Comment: @DikeshGandhi but i do not think it will be very professional to mention to our clients that they need to use chrome if they want to print list items.. i was looking for a more robust solution that will work cross browsers....

Comment: you are right. That's why I had mentioned this as not exact solution. In this case, you need to create custom development for the same.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint does not include this capability.

You may be able to use JSLink on the list view to do formatting along with other JavaScript and CSS in a Content Editor web part or Script Editor web part to get the browser print function to do what you want.

What I do in this situation is use SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) which is a report writer, and allows a SharePoint list to be used as a Data Source. I format the report exactly as I like and put a button on the list view using a CEWP or SEWP to run the report.

Comment: i think the SQL server reporting will be too much effort and create dependencies on my farm, which i always try to avoid as much as possible... now JSLINK appraoch you proposed looks promising,, but can you provide some examples of how i  can use javascript to do such a thing ? now i find some examples on the web which shows how i can add a print button on my display form, which will open the browser Print dialog.. but i need to have a custom template to show the logo, current site name, print date, items in a user friendly format... so is this possible using jslink and jabvascripts?

Comment: Note - You don't need to install SSRS in the farm (I.e. SharePoint Integrated Mode). You can use SSRS Native Mode. This is how I have it installed. You can still use a list as a data source.

Comment: yes i know that i will not need to install sSRS inside the farm... but your approach might work but i think it is somehow complex to provide a printing capabilities... i prefer to achieve this using JSLINK ,, but i could not find any document which describe this